# Laravel Cashier setting the quality with newSubscription for Stripe

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am developing a Laravel application. I am installing Stripe payment method using the Cashier. Now, I am having a bit of an issue setting up quality for the Stripe plan on creating new subscription. This is how I create new subscription.

```
auth()->user()->newSubscription('prod_xxx', 'plan_x')-xx>create(request('stripeToken'));
```

The above code works perfectly fine. But when I tried to set the quality like this

```
auth()->user()->newSubscription('prod_xxx', 'plan_x')->updateQuality(5)->create(request('stripeToken'));
```

It does not work. It is saying updateQuality method does not exist. How can I set the quality with newSubscription all in one go?

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/billing#subscription-quantity

You want `updateQuantity` instead, I believe.

Comment: So it would be two steps. Create the subscription. Then update the quality of the existing application.

Comment: Seems like it, I'm not too familiar with Lavarel so maybe there's a way to set this as an option on `newSubscription`, but two steps will work.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never, this might help others.

```php
auth()->user()
    ->newSubscription('prod_xxx', 'plan_x')
    ->quantity(5)
    ->create(request('stripeToken'));
```